# Automate batch processing using cloud functions from google cloud storage to bigquery - something is missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

**What I want to achieve:**
Everytime i upload a file to Cloud Storage, it will automatically be write append to BigQuery.

**What I have worked on:**
Cloud storage triggers cloud function is working fine.
Dataflow template Cloud Storage to Big Query is working fine.

However they don't work together. How can I have the cloud functions trigger to activate the dataflow part? Is it a script or just some settings I have missed out?

Something is missing to connect them all. I'm relatively new to this, I've been searching for tutorials on this but I don't know if I have been searching for the wrong keywords, i can't find any relevant tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, your desired workflow will be:

**Cloud Function ---> Google Cloud Storage (GCS) ---> Cloud Dataflow ---> BigQuery**

And, the most important part for you would be how to trigger a Dataflow job when a new file is written in GCS. There isn't such a feature in GCS to do so. You will need to orchestrate this somehow.

For that, you can add another Cloud Function that will be [triggered on a new file creation in GCS bucket](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize). And, in that Cloud Function you just start a Dataflow pipeline.

The architecture will end up in something like:

**Cloud Function 1 ---> GCS ---> Cloud Function 2 ---> Dataflow job ---> BigQuery**

Where **Cloud Function 1** is your current Cloud function, and **Cloud Function 2** is the new one that is trigger when a new file arrives to a bucket and launch your Dataflow Job.

I'd like to mention that you can avoid the creation of the second Cloud Function and the Dataflow Job if you instead of having a native table in BigQuery, you choose to have an [External Table in GCS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage). It has pros and cons. Depending on your case might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest) for Dataflow and I think this will be the option for you.

When you take a look on examples in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#running-the-cloud-storage-text-to-bigquery-stream-template) you can choose between console, `gcloud` and API in each example. So if you have currently working template and you are running it using console or `gcloud` you have just to convert it to POST request like shown in API.

You can test the request in appropriate tools (for ex. using [POSTMAN](https://www.postman.com/)). When you will have working POST request than you have to create Cloud Function in your preferred language were you will create the request. For nodejs you can use [this](https://nodejs.dev/learn/make-an-http-post-request-using-nodejs), for Python [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/making-http-requests-in-python?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=1455363063&utm_adgroupid=65083631748&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=332602034364&utm_targetid=dsa-429603003980&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=9067436&gclid=CjwKCAiAp4KCBhB6EiwAxRxbpNIFDKPEr0nyMEvx--Gmwct7eaWBH3Lq9v0qkcvWzaORdnW3t4hUcBoCEWcQAvD_BwE) and I am sure you will be able to google tones of examples for any language to choose in Cloud Function.